# Copy secondary database records in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

There is a requirement where I need to copy records from secondary database to primary database.

So here is what I am doing, I have two databases (active and standby). Active has two tables a primary table and secondary, similarly standby has two tables primary and secondary. Both the database has same schema

I am copying the records from standby to active (both primary and secondary). While copying the records I am skipping the sequence number since sequence number is the primary key and auto generated. So it will generate new sequence numbers for the records copied from standby to active.

Active database primary table contains a column Results which may contain PASS or FAIL

Standby DB:(primary table) sequence_number is primary key

- sequence_number Name Age Results
- 100    Raj   27   Pass
- 101    Kumar 26   Fail

The records which has Results Pass contains subject and percentage in the secondary table, sequence_number is the foreign key here

- sequence_number Subject Percentage
- 101   Maths 77%
- 101   Science 80%

There is no problem while copying the records between the primary tables

After copying,

- sequence_number Name Age Results
- 12    Raj   27   Pass
- 13    Kumar 26   Fail

But the problem here I face is for the secondary tables, since the sequence_number won't be maintained

After copying (skipping sequence numbers)

- sequence_number Subject Percentage
- NULL  Maths 77%
- NULL   Science 80%

But I need a record like,

- sequence_number Subject Percentage
- 12   Maths 77%
- 12   Science 80%

Only sequence number is the relation between primary and secondary tables, since we are skipping the sequence number I am not sure how to update the sequence number in the secondary tables after the records are copied.

Kindly help

Thanks

Comment: By mistake. It is  MySQL

Comment: How do you know "12"; I see not way to tie "Maths 77%" to "Raj".